# each child in an array unique key with react native swipe out

Tags: arrays, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

i'm using react native swipeout within a flat list. I'm pulling my data from a collection in firestore. I want to pull the items in the collection and apply a color to the item based on the item type. For instance, if someone has a car then it would be purple view and the bike would be green. I applied an if statement and then render method based on the if statement. Can someone help me on what i'm doing wrong?

```
if (collection.item.type == 'car') {
  let that = this;
    return (
      <View style={{marginTop: 20}}>
    {/* this is an empty view to space out the array items. was unable to figure out a more clever way to separate the views and keep the side buttons in line with the component.*/} 
      <Swipeout 
        key={collection.key}
        onOpen={(itemID, ) => {
          that.setState({
            itemID,
          });
        }}
        style={{backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}
        right={swipeoutBtns}>
        <LinearGradient style={{justifyContent: 'center', borderRadius: 30, width: 250, height: 180, alignSelf: 'center'}} colors={['#ff00ff', '#0066ff']}>
                  <View style={{alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', width: 60, height: 60, borderRadius: 60/2, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                      <Text style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                      {car}
                      </Text>
                  </View>
                  <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 5, color: 'white', fontSize: 16, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                    {collection.item.make}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 5, color: 'white', fontSize: 16, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                    {collection.item.model}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 5, color: 'white', fontSize: 16, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                    {collection.item.color}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', marginTop: 5, color: 'white', fontSize: 16, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                    {collection.item.year}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'white', fontSize: 16, alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',}}>
                    {collection.item.licensePlate}
                  </Text>
            </LinearGradient> 
      </Swipeout>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add item.key to the key extractor props. I'm answering this for anyone else that has this problem.

keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}